# Problem with showing convergence or divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Determine if the following series is absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent.
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4}$$

So I showed that$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\bigl|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4}\bigr|$ is divergent using limit comparison test.

Now for $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4}$, I considered 2 ways:

1. Alternating Series Test
   $$a_n:=\frac{1}{3n+4}$$
   $$3n+4>0\implies \frac{1}{3n+4}>0\implies a_n\ge0$$
   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{3n+4}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{3+\frac{4}{n}}=\frac{0}{3+0}=0$$
   $$3n+4\le 3n+7\implies a_n=\frac{1}{3n+4}\ge \frac{1}{3n+7}=a_{n+1}$$
   Therefore $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4}$ is convergent.
2. Comparison Test (Note: $3n+4\ge0$)
   $$-1\le(-1)^{n+1}\le 1 \implies \frac{-1}{3n+4} \le \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4} \le \frac{1}{3n+4}$$

But I have already showed that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{3n+4}$ diverges.
and consequently, $-\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{3n+4}$ diverges as well. So that would imply that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4}$ is divergent!

Did i make a computational error somewhere? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternating test is OK.

Now, there is no contradition with your second point, because
$$
\frac{-1}{3n+4} \le \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4} \le \frac{1}{3n+4}
$$ yields
$$
-\infty \le \sum_{n\geq1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{3n+4} \le +\infty
$$ which **does not exclude convergence** of the initial series.

Comment: hmm. So does that mean that the comparison test fails (aka not helpful) to determine convergence? If so how do i know when to choose between alternating test and comparison test? Thanks for the response btw!

Comment: @Danxe The answer is yes. The comparison test is more suitable for a series with positive terms.

Comment: Alright. Thanks for the insight!